# Why is my picker view's viewForRow transparent?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I want an opaque `viewForRow` for a `pickerView` instance of `UIPickerView`. What I'm doing now results in a semi-transparent view!
Here's what I have:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    weak var pickerView: UIPickerView! {
        didSet {
            pickerView.dataSource = self
            pickerView.delegate = self
            pickerView.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
            pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true
            pickerView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100)
            view.addSubview(pickerView)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerView = UIPickerView()
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        let rowSize = pickerView.rowSizeForComponent(component)
        let aView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rowSize.width, height: rowSize.height))
        aView.opaque = true
        aView.backgroundColor = .blackColor()
        return aView
    }
}
```

You can see the `ViewController`'s `view` background behind `aView`. Why? And can this be fixed?

Many thanks.

Comment: If you don't want to see the view controller's view behind the picker, why did you make the picker view's background clear?

Comment: @rmaddy Because I want the picker view to have a clear background with views that are opaque. Is there a solution for this?